# "Punchline" is to "joke" as ----- is to "scary story"

Tags: single-word-requests

When telling a short scary story, there's often a "*punchline*" that triggers the fear the story is trying to create. You know, that moment when your audience gets wide-eyed and gasps.

Is there a better way to refer to this than just a "*punchline*" in the context of a scary story and not a joke?

Comment: [*Denouement*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/denouement), perhaps?

Comment: If it involves revelation, call it a "reveal." Or you can call it the "climax."

Comment: +1 for "climax", I immediately thought the same when I saw the question.

Comment: Maybe "clincher"?

Comment: One word for it is 'kicker'.

Comment: Punchline is probably at least as applicable. Punch, in the sense of punching something up, applies equally to a laugh or scare.

Comment: Punchline is to joke as Hammer Films is to scary story!

Answer (score 2):

I think "stinger" is the best word for this. Traditionally it means an abrupt sound effect that enhances a jump scare in a horror movie.

Comment: This seems good, do you have any references?

Comment: Looking into it "stinger" might actually be a colloquialism, I can only find a wiki page for the broad concept of a "sting": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sting_(musical_phrase)

Comment: But "stinger" is fairly common in the community: http://birthmoviesdeath.com/2014/10/20/the-ten-scariest-film-scores-ever-composed http://filmsound.org/articles/horrorsound/horrorsound.htm http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/9641/common-horror-genre-type-stingers